# Eigenvalues, stability, Granger causality for a VAR(1) model

Tags: self-study, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

[image]

I know I have to check the eigenvalues for the stability condition in general but I do not know how to process this exercise. How can I bring it in the right form?
How do you check c) ?

[image]Can anyone help with showing the single steps?

---

For c) I would say that c does not G-cause y becaue of the 0 in the matrix. But y G-causes c.

Comment: Granger causality in the variable of some equation is present if any of the lags of the other variable(s - but here we only have one) are nonzero.

Comment: Thank you. How would you attempt a); I would check for unit roots.

Comment: @Christoph Hanck how can I brind the equation in world representation from?

Comment: for a) you indeed may look at the appropriate eigenvalues

Comment: How can I bring the given equation in the right format?

Comment: @Christoph Hanck Do you check the eigenvalue for ct and yt separately?

Comment: Isnt it just necessary to impose restrictions on alpha and gamma?

Comment: not sure how to tackel d)

Comment: Please read up on impulse responses.

Comment: I did! I got it now. But not sure how to tackle e) Sorry. I meant e) before

Comment: Me neither. There is no e) in your screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the roots of 
$$
det(I-Az)=0,
$$
where $A$ is your coefficient matrix on the lags.

Thus,
$$
det\left(I-\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\0&\gamma\end{pmatrix}z\right)=det\begin{pmatrix}1-\alpha z&-\beta\\-0&1-\gamma z\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
or
$$
(1-\alpha z)(1-\gamma z)=0
$$
which has solutions
$$z_1=1/\alpha\quad z_2=1/\gamma,$$
which need to be outside the unit circle. You can take it from here.

Comment: For a) I would suggest that alpha and gamma need to be between 0 and 1 to have a stable process because then the roots are bigger than 1 in absolute value.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same result. But then I also defined the parameters and said that $\alpha$ has to be between 0 and 1  (and between -1 and 0) as I need z bigger than 1 in absolute values to define a stable system.

Comment: Right, that is what I'm saying.